# Regex for currency and amount C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a regex for the following outputs:

```
Text         -                  Output Expected

$200                     currency sign = "$" and amount = 200
€ 20.34                  currency sign = "€" and amount = 20.34
£ 190,234                currency sign = "£" and amount = 190234
$  20.34                 currency sign = "$" and amount = 20.34
```

I am not good with regex but still I want to do this with regex. Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Comment: The most important question is: what is a well-formed string, and what happens to malformed strings?

Comment: Do you have anything yet? And as I understand it, you will only get the currency and the amount and nothing else with the input, right? Can the currencies be anything or only the symbols you have above?

Comment: currency can only the symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
(\D)\s*([.\d,]+)
```

the caputre group 1 will contain currency symbol and group 2 contians value

see the demo http://regex101.com/r/eV2uZ7/1

**EXPLANTION**

`(\D)` mathces anything other than digit

`\s*` matches any number of spaces.

`[.\d,]+` matches digits, comma and dot.

To be more specific you can also give `\d[.\d,]*` which ensures that the value part always begin with a digit

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex to capture symbol and amout :

```
/(?<SYMBOL>[$€£]){1}\s*(?<AMOUNT>[\d.,]+)/g
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dH9hM0/1) (Look at the match information on the right panel)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
([$€£]) *([0-9.,]*)
```

Capture group 1 will be the currency symbol, capture group 2 will be the amount also you will need to remove **","** after that with Replace(',','')

Comment: thanks for the answer but currency can be anything and I have no prior knowledge about the signs

Comment: Yes you will need to add more symbols yourself from a list there is almost no other way if you dont want this to be error prone

Answer (score 0):

```
    string str = string.Empty , outPut = string.Empty;
        Regex paternWithDot = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)+");
        Regex paternWithComa = new Regex(@"\d+(\,\d+)+");
        Match match = null;


        str = "& 34.34";
        if (str.Contains(".")) match = paternWithDot.Match(str);
        if (str.Contains(",")) match = paternWithComa.Match(str);
        outPut += string.Format( @" currency sign = ""{0}"" and amount = {1}" , str.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty),  match.Value) + Environment.NewLine;


        str = "€ 20.34 ";
        if (str.Contains(".")) match = paternWithDot.Match(str);
        if (str.Contains(",")) match = paternWithComa.Match(str);
        outPut += string.Format(@" currency sign = ""{0}"" and amount = {1}", str.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty), match.Value) + Environment.NewLine;

        str = "£ 190,234";
        if (str.Contains(".")) match = paternWithDot.Match(str);
        if (str.Contains(",")) match = paternWithComa.Match(str);
        outPut += string.Format(@" currency sign = ""{0}"" and amount = {1}", str.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty), match.Value) + Environment.NewLine;

        str = "$  20.34 ";
        if (str.Contains(".")) match = paternWithDot.Match(str);
        if (str.Contains(",")) match = paternWithComa.Match(str);
        outPut += string.Format(@" currency sign = ""{0}"" and amount = {1}", str.Replace(match.Value, string.Empty), match.Value) + Environment.NewLine;

        MessageBox.Show(outPut);
```